# iPad Simulator Corrupted

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

Im running the latest version of Xcode on mountain Lion.  My iPad Simulator seems to has got corrupted.   All my ipad apps just appear as an iphone sized screen in the top left with a corrupted graphical status bar including new projects and old projects.

[image: Screen]

Anybody come across this? Ive reset content and settings in the simulator.

Is a clean intall the only option here?

Comment: I think you can only try a clean install...

Comment: Deleted an re installed xcode and still the same

Comment: then, try to test on a real iPad.

Comment: How does that sort my simulator issue?

Comment: it won't. using the simulator is good temporary solution when you do not have a real device. if you have a real device, just use it bravely.

Comment: I got this today, but after rebooting os x it was ok. I'm guessing you've tried that though.

Comment: Yeah tried that, nothing helped, installed new Xcode and that sorted it.  Thanks for the reply though.